# Laravel token middleware

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I want to make my API unavailable to every client who doesn't have the token to access. This means the Android app will send a `client` as Android and `token` as token string in the header with keys `client` and `token`.

Now in middleware, I am checking it with my table fields to pass through authorization. If both match, then I will authorize and if don't then it will send a 403 response.

I am aware of Passport but it is not what I am looking for. In fact, consider it as a first layer of security and then use Passport as a second layer of security to authorize the API.

**Is this code correct?**

As I am not so familiar with Laravel - Middleware I just want to get some feedback from experts whether the code I have written is accurate and up to the standard. If not, I would appreciate your suggestion and help to make it better.

#### Middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\ApiToken;
use Closure;
use function response;

class ApiAccess
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle( $request, Closure $next ) {

        if ( $this->checkToken( $request ) ) {
            return $next( $request );
        }

        return response()->json( [ 'error' => 'Unauthorized' ], 403 );


    }

    public function checkToken( $request ) {

        $client = $request->header( 'client' );
        $token  = $request->header( 'token' );

        $checkToken = ApiToken::where( 'client', $client )
                              ->where( 'token', $token )->first();

        return $checkToken;
    }
}
```

### API Route

I am fetching results from the `ApiToken` table just to check:

```
Route::get('/', function(Request $request) {
    return ApiToken::all();
})->middleware('apiAccess');
```

### Optimized with [Muhammad Nauman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8140865/muhammad-nauman)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49831270/1053190)

```
public function checkToken( $request ) {

    $client = $request->header( 'client' );
    $token  = $request->header( 'token' );

    return ApiToken::where( 'client', $client )
                          ->where( 'token', $token )->exists();
// Nicer, and it will return true and false based on the existence of the token and client.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on this is the following:

1. rename the middleware to something meaningful (I took example from **VerifyCsrfToken** middleware)
2. throw exception if token is mismatched
3. rename `checkToken` to `verify`, reader of the code knows that code checks/verifies token because thats the point of the middleware
4. simplify even more `verify` function and add docblock
5. optimize the query to the following

   > ```
   > select exists(select `id` from `tokens` where (`client` = 'Android' and `token` = 'OuK0ELzYkN3Ss9Zf')) as `exists`
   > ```

So ApiAccess becomes following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Exceptions\TokenMismatchException;
use App\ApiToken;
use Closure;

class VerifyApiToken
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \App\Exceptions\TokenMismatchException
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->verify($request)) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        throw new TokenMismatchException;
    }


    /**
     * Verify token by querying database for existence of the client:token pair specified in headers.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function verify($request): bool //optional return types
    {
        return ApiToken::select('id')->where([    // add select so Eloquent does not query for all fields
            'client' => $request->header('client'), // remove variable that is used only once
            'token'  => $request->header('token'),  // remove variable that is used only once
        ])->exists();
    }
}
```

Create new Exception, `php artisan make:exception TokenMismatchException` - yes kind of same as Laravel's stock one used when CSRF token is mismatched.

With body:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class TokenMismatchException extends Exception
{

    /**
     * Report the exception.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function report()
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Render the exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|null
     */
    public function render($request)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) { // if request has `Accept: application/json` header present
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 403);
        }

        return abort(403);
    }
}
```

> **Note**: remove `use function response;` statements because helpers are auto-loaded from Laravel's helpers